# Iterate over JS

Tags: javascript

I am unable to do this

Write a function to take pokemon’s name as argument and display the
information of that pokemon

My code is

```js
var FullGame = {
  "pokemon": [{
    "id": 1,
    "num": "001",
    "name": "Bulbasaur",
    "img": "http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/pokemon/001.png",
    "type": [
      "Grass",
      "Poison"
    ],
    "height": "0.71 m",
    "weight": "6.9 kg",
    "candy": "Bulbasaur Candy",
    "candy_count": 25,
    "egg": "2 km",
    "spawn_chance": 0.69,
    "avg_spawns": 69,
    "spawn_time": "20:00",
    "multipliers": [1.58],
    "weaknesses": [
      "Fire",
      "Ice",
      "Flying",
      "Psychic"
    ],
    "next_evolution": [{
      "num": "002",
      "name": "Ivysaur"
    }, {
      "num": "003",
      "name": "Venusaur"
    }]
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "num": "002",
    "name": "Ivysaur",
    "img": "http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/pokemon/002.png",
    "type": [
      "Grass",
      "Poison"
    ],
    "height": "0.99 m",
    "weight": "13.0 kg",
    "candy": "Bulbasaur Candy",
    "candy_count": 100,
    "egg": "Not in Eggs",
    "spawn_chance": 0.042,
    "avg_spawns": 4.2,
    "spawn_time": "07:00",
    "multipliers": [
      1.2,
      1.6
    ],
    "weaknesses": [
      "Fire",
      "Ice",
      "Flying",
      "Psychic"
    ],
    "prev_evolution": [{
      "num": "001",
      "name": "Bulbasaur"
    }],
    "next_evolution": [{
      "num": "003",
      "name": "Venusaur"
    }]
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "num": "003",
    "name": "Venusaur",
    "img": "http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/pokemon/003.png",
    "type": [
      "Grass",
      "Poison"
    ],
    "height": "2.01 m",
    "weight": "100.0 kg",
    "candy": "Bulbasaur Candy",
    "egg": "Not in Eggs",
    "spawn_chance": 0.017,
    "avg_spawns": 1.7,
    "spawn_time": "11:30",
    "multipliers": null,
    "weaknesses": [
      "Fire",
      "Ice",
      "Flying",
      "Psychic"
    ],
    "prev_evolution": [{
      "num": "001",
      "name": "Bulbasaur"
    }, {
      "num": "002",
      "name": "Ivysaur"
    }]
  }]
};



var name = prompt('Enter the name of Pokemon');

var DetailOfPokemon = function(name, FullGame) {

  for (var currentPokemon in FullGame) {
    if (FullGame.pokemon[currentPokemon].name == name) {
      var Detail = FullGame.pokemon[currentPokemon];
      alert(Detail);
    } else {
      alert("Type Again");
    }
  }
};
DetailOfPokemon(name, FullGame);
```

Comment: what does "unable to" mean? What happens to your code when you run it?

Comment: After taking the input from the user, it does not show the detail of that pokemon

Comment: Well that much I guessed. Technical error information and/or detailed description of the unexpected behaviour was what I meant. I've converted your code into a runnable snippet. Now you can probably see you have a JS error

Comment: You currently loop at the root of you json, but there is juste 1 key there ("pokemon") and it has no name proprety. You need to loop on `FullGame.pokemon`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json). Read this to understand how to work with JS objects, and use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) to see what all the different components are.

Comment: @GalAbra but `currentPokemon` is an index here, not the name ! So this part of the code works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You where comparing the wrong array in your code, you can fix it like following:

```
for (var currentPokemon in FullGame.pokemon) { // HERE added .pokemon at the end
  if (FullGame.pokemon[currentPokemon].name == name) {
    var Detail = FullGame.pokemon[currentPokemon];
    alert(Detail);
  } else {
    alert("Type Again");
  }
}
```

Comment: please help in this problem                                                                                  Write a function that take a “Weakness” as an input and gives the names
of all pokemon who have that Weakness. (check the weakness array in
the dataset)

Comment: this is my code                                                                                                   var weakness = prompt('Enter the weakness');
 
 var WeaknessName = function(weakness,FullGame) {
  for(var presentPokemon in FullGame.pokemon) {
   for(var j = 0; j < FullGame.pokemon.weaknesses.length; j++) {
   if(FullGame.pokemon[presentPokemon].weaknesses.toString() == weakness) {
    var pokemonName = FullGame.pokemon[presentPokemon].name;
    alert(pokemonName);
    break;
   }
   }
  }
 };
 
 WeaknessName(weakness,FullGame);

Comment: @Kunal ask a new question if you have a new question. But really you should be able to take the learning from this question and apply it to the new one, it's the same kind of process, just looking at another part of the data.